# Sending sms through e-mail, using Twilio

Tags: email, automation, sms, twilio

In using [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/) to send message(sms/text) to a phone. It is said that every phone number has an email id linked to it. This will be used to send the sms through twilio API.

However, I am not able to send sms to phone numbers other than the one with which I registered.
Sending sms to myself is not much fun. What am I missing in the twilio API or the e-mail id linked to every mobile number by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can only [send SMS messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) to yourself (or numbers that you verify in the Twilio console) when you are using a trial account. If you upgrade your account and add a credit card or PayPal account on file then you will be able to send SMS messages to the numbers you have in your system.